# Следует ли как то самостоятельно распределять нагрузку между потоками, при работе с epoll?

Tags: многопоточность, unix, асинхронность, epoll

При работе с несколькими потоками(не процессами) и epoll, следует ли мне самому разрабатывать алгоритм распределения, или достаточно во всех потоках вызвать epoll_wait и он сам разбудит нужный? Или могут происходить ошибки, к примеру 2 epoll_wait проснулись одновременно. Я знаю, что при использовании нескольких процессов, где один и тот же дескриптор мониторится несколькими epoll дескрипторами следует использовать флаг EPOLLEXCLUSIVE, но требуется ли подобные меры при одном дескрипторе и нескольких потоках.

Comment: *`"If more than maxevents file descriptors are ready when epoll_wait()
       is called, then successive epoll_wait() calls will round robin
       through the set of ready file descriptors."`* .  Попробуйте разные варианты  и напишите нам о результатах....